# array_unique() for a 2d array, but based on a single column only

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, duplicates, filtering, unique

For instance

```
[
    ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2],
    ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 3],
    ['foo' => 2, 'bar' => 4]
]
```

I'd like to become

```
[
    ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2],
    ['foo' => 2, 'bar' => 4]
]
```

Based on the duplicate value for `foo`.  I'm not bothered which of the entries goes, either is fine.

I can write something to loop over the array and perform this check myself, but I wondered if there's a built-in function (or combination of a couple of them) that can achieve this result?

Comment: @Justinas no.. please check. the link work if both values are identical : https://3v4l.org/1KVBe

Comment: _but I wondered if there's a built-in function (or combination of a couple of them)_ -> No do it through loop